# Problems with sorting the characters of a word

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem that I have been struggling with for some time.
I am given a word consisting of small or large letters of the English alphabet, to sort the characters so that in the first positions appear the characters that appear most often in the word, and if they appear by the same number of times, they will be sorted lexicographical.
Such as:

> input:
>   Instructions
>
> output:
>   iinnssttcoru

So far I have written this, but from here I do not know how to sort them and display properly, a tip?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String testString = " ";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    testString = rd.readLine();
    Map<Character, List<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
        char someChar = testString.charAt(i);
        if (someChar == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        char ch = testString.charAt(i);
        List<Character> characters = map.getOrDefault(Character.toLowerCase(ch), new ArrayList<>());
        characters.add(ch);
        map.put(Character.toLowerCase(ch), characters);
    }
    List<Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());}
```

Comment: What versin of java are you using?  is performance a concern?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TreeMap` `counterAppear` with the `key` is the number of repetitions of the character and value is a list of characters has the same number of `key` repetitions. This list needs to be sorted before printing to ensure the order as required. Use `TreeMap` to make sure the map is sorted by key(the number of repetitions).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String testString = " ";
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        testString = rd.readLine();
        Map<Character, List<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
            char someChar = testString.charAt(i);
            if (someChar == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            char ch = testString.charAt(i);
            //Change to Optimize Code
            Character keyCharacter = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            if (map.get(keyCharacter) == null) {
                map.put(keyCharacter, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            List<Character> characters = map.get(keyCharacter);
            characters.add(ch);
        }
        TreeMap<Integer, List<Character>> counterAppear = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Character character = entry.getKey();
            int repeatCharTime = entry.getValue().size();
            if (counterAppear.get(repeatCharTime) == null) {
                counterAppear.put(repeatCharTime, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            List<Character> characters = counterAppear.get(repeatCharTime);
            characters.add(character);
        }

        for (Integer repeatCharTime : counterAppear.descendingKeySet()) {
            List<Character> keyCharacters = counterAppear.get(repeatCharTime);
            Collections.sort(keyCharacters);
            for (Character character : keyCharacters) {
                for (int i = 0; i < repeatCharTime; i++) {
                    System.err.print(character);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a short info on why it should be 'Iinnssttruco' instead of 'Iinnssttcoru'. As brief as you can (i.e. `r` is exicographically than `c`). Also I'd ask OP what is the real meaning behind `someChar == ' '`, because string or character sequence which has a whitespace it cannot represent a single word.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the previous answer and I updated as above @itwasntme . ```someChar == ' '``` was given by the author, I don't care about this place. I have assumed that ```someChar='Instructions'```

Comment: prog.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
            map.computeIfAbsent(keyCharacter, k -> new ArrayList<>());                                 
A problem on the site when I compile the problem. Possible because they are compiling with java 7?

Comment: @KikoLoko I used lambda expression in java 8.

Comment: You can try again with the code above, which deleted the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    static void process(String s)
    {
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for(Character c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
        {
            Integer nb = map.get(c);
            map.put(c, nb==null ? 1 : nb+1);
        }

        ArrayList<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, (a,b) ->
        {
            int res = b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue());
            if(res!=0)
                return res;
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
        });

        for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : list)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<e.getValue();i++)
                System.out.print(e.getKey());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        process("Instructions");
    }
}
```